# Regular Expression to replace unknown value in text file - c# and asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I'd like to replace a line in a text file using a c# function in asp.net. The line is:

> SQL-SERVER-VERSION="some unknown value"

I don't know what the value after = might be so I need to use a wildcard for this. I want the new line to read:

> SQL-SERVER-VERSION="2008"

I'm trying to use Regex.Replace but no matter what regular expression I try, it doesn't work.
Can anybody help?
Thanks,
John

Comment: OK, so what did you try? If you don't tell us, we can only guess what didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what you already tried so I can't tell you what you were doing wrong, but the following should work:

```
string s = "SQL-SERVER-VERSION=\"some unknown value\"";
s = Regex.Replace(s, "SQL\\-SERVER\\-VERSION=\".*\"", "SQL-SERVER-VERSION=\"2008\"");
```

Comment: This fails; for example, if the string is only `SQL-SERVER-VERSION=""` and I think the desired output would be to have the 2008 in there.

Comment: I made the assumption that there was already some value in those quotes, but fair enough, I changed the `+` to a `*` and now that's covered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  Regex rgx = new Regex(@"SQL-SERVER-VERSION="".*?""");
  string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```

It looks a little messy in a .NET string but the pure regex looks like this:

```
SQL-SERVER-VERSION=".*?"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that " won't appear in the value then you could locate the string using

SQL-SERVER-VERSION=".*"

and replace with SQL-SERVER-VERSION="2008"

e.g

```
strInput = Regex.Replace( strInput, "SQL-SERVER-VERSION="".*""", "SQL-SERVER-VERSION=""2008""")
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if a `"` appears in the string -- `*` is greedy by default and will find the last quote in the string (which is presumably what the OP wants.)

Comment: @ean5533, why do you assume that the OP wants a greedy match?

Comment: Because it makes more sense than assuming otherwise. The OP's example line ends with a quote. Sounds to me like the OP wants everything up to the last quote, which is at the end of the line.

Comment: @ean5533 Good point. So use ".*" for a greedy match or otherwise ".*?"